# jquery validation and form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, validation

I am trying to validate a form and then submit it using jquery . But the submit is not getting called. I dont know what is going wrong.

```
$('#save_vehicle').click(function(e){
            validate_form(e);
});
// VALIDATION FUNCTION
    function validate_form(e) {
        if($("#manufacturer").val()=="select"){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Please Select Manufacturer');
            return false;
        } else if($("#models").val()=="select") {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('Please Select Model');
            return false;
        }  else {           
            return true;
            $('#frm_add').submit();
        }
    }
```

****NOTE : **** `save_vehicle` is the SUBMIT button id. `frm_add` is the id of the form.

Can someone please point out my mistake. Thanks in advance

Comment: shoulndt you be returngin true after submit?

Comment: It is happening because you are returning true before calling the submit function. Just remove return true from the else condition

Comment: Yes. It worked. But I am confused as why `return true` was creating problem?

Comment: @Roger if you use return statement anywhere..the execution should not goes to next line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing:

```
else {           
   return true;
   $('#frm_add').submit(); //will never be called as you returned already above
}
```

to

```
else {           
   $('#frm_add').submit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain why `return true` was creating problem?

Comment: @Roger "return" will stop JavaScript from executing the rest of the script, so "return true;" would avoid your submit() call..

Answer (score 2):

```
   else {     
         $('#frm_add').submit();
        }
```

no need of return true.

@Roger if you use return statement anywhere..the execution should not goes to next line..